# a direct, simple api to run as system?

Tags: c, windows

Suppose a program is running with elevated privileges already, and it needs to see the contents of the System Volume Information folder, and by default, only NT Authority\System can do that. A workaround would be to change ACL's on the folder, but I don't want to mess with that. I already found two ways to do it: the task scheduler and psexec. They are too indirect, I don't even need to describe the first one, and the second one works by installing a windows service, running it, telling it to run whatever I wanted to run, then uninstalling the service. Now the question is: is there a direct, simple WinAPI function to run something as system? I don't think that such an API would circumvent the security restrictions, as an administrator I have the right to schedule a task or install a service, so there must be a shortcut.

UPDATE: if there's an actual API to specifically tell me the contents of System Volume Information, then it would be perfect, no need to run as system.

Comment: I think you are looking for CreateProcessAsUser

Comment: how do I get a token from LogonUser which needs a password?

Comment: Try to get token from any system process if your app has enough rights for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to change folder's ACL. Instead you can change ACL of your process. It is done by set of Impersonate functions (ImpersonateLoggedOnUser for example)

Comment: ImpersonateLoggedOnUser needs a token from LogonUser, which requires a password. How do I work around that?

Comment: @fejesjoco - no account, no miracles. Security system of Windows would not permit you perform any action out of security realms. There is no special back-door API to cheat this. Instead think about some workarounds: (*)Create special account that you manage and impersonate to it (for example IIS do it). (*) Create special windows service that is started from system account and do some job for your application. (*) Ask user to run some featured task from privileged account

Comment: There's no cheating, because I'm an administrator, I can install services and eventually run as system, I just wondered if there's a shortcut. You know, if I CAN do something, then why do I need tricks to achieve it? Anyway, creating a user account sounds a lot better than a service, because impersonating a user in my local process is much easier than spawning and communicating with a service. I'll look into it if I can create a user with system rights.

Comment: Stealing tokens actually works, so I accept it. DReJ suggested a similar way, but you were the first, so I'll accept this. Also see my blog about my findings: http://joco.name/2010/12/31/how-to-impersonate-the-windows-system-account-in-an-application/